# CURL php in Google developers Console

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl, telegram-bot

I'm using Google Developers Console to build a bot for telegram.

everything works fine, except that when I try to send files (photo, audio, etc ..) php returns a fatal error for the lack of libraries Curl.

I checked and this is the php version 5.5.26, and also supports the new function CURLFile.

How can I fix?

I leave you the error that returns the console

1 - Method

```
    function sendIMG($api_url,$path,$chatID)
{
  $url = $api_url."sendPhoto?chat_id=".$chatID ;

  $post_fields = array(
      'chat_id'   => $chatID,
      'photo'     => new \CURLFile(realpath($path))
  );

  $ch = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields); 
  $output = curl_exec($ch);

  sendText($api_url, $chatID, $output);
}
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CURLFile' not found in /base/data/home/apps/s~macabreobot/1.389444928540417808/main.php on line 18

2 Method

```
    function sendIMG_2($api_url,$path,$chatID)
{
  $api_url = "https://api.telegram.org/botYOUR_BOT_TOKEN/";
  $url = $api_url."sendPhoto?chat_id=".$chatID;

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("photo" => "@".$path)); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($path));

  $output = curl_exec($ch);

  sendText($api_url, $chatID, $output);
}
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /base/data/home/apps/s~macabreobot/1.389445039709239473/main.php on line 36

Answer (score 0):

There are some configuration steps needed to use curl_ functions on App Engine PHP, see Terrence Ryan's [blog post](http://terrenceryan.com/blog/index.php/php-on-app-engine-does-curl/) on the subject for more details.